# how do you insert a variable into a url

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to insert a variable in a url link in javascript but it's not letting me do it, it keeps looking for a file...
here is the code:

```
var pic = element.src;
document.getElementById('image').style.backgroundImage='url(pic)'
```

question is how I can insert the variable into the url link..the pic is a link to a photo on a website.

Comment: `....backgroundImage='url('+pic+')';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
document.getElementById('image').style.backgroundImage='url('+pic+')'
```

To concadenate variable in string, you need to use `+` in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that url(pic) is a string. Try string concatenation instead like:

```
document.getElementById('image').style.backgroundImage='url(' + pic + ')';
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to concatenate the *`url(`* and `pic` and  *`)`*

```
document.getElementById('image').style.backgroundImage='url(' + pic + ')';
```